# How to receive intent on loading an url in android browser in an app

Tags: android

I want my android app to receive the url info of web pages opened using the android web browser. This should happen dynamically when my app is running in the background. Is it possible? Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like **Service** in android .

please refer http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html
.

Hope it will help you